# Adding both short long gestures in same view with proper differentiation

Tags: ios, objective-c, touch, uigesturerecognizer

I am working on app in which I want both short long gesture in same view, I added but issue is I'm facing is that short gesture end always call, Need your help how to do that in right way. Below is my code.

```
        UILongPressGestureRecognizer *longGesture = [[UILongPressGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(longGestureOnFormFields:)];
    longGesture.minimumPressDuration = 1.0f;
    [longGesture setDelegate:self];
    [self addGestureRecognizer:longGesture];

    UILongPressGestureRecognizer *shortGesture = [[UILongPressGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(shortGesture:)];
    shortGesture.minimumPressDuration = 0.1f;
    [shortGesture setDelegate:self];
    [self addGestureRecognizer:shortGesture];

- (void)longGestureOnFormFields:(UIGestureRecognizer*) recogniser
{
    if (recogniser.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded ) {
}
- (void)shortGesture:(UIGestureRecognizer*) recogniser
    {
        if (recogniser.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded ) {
}
```

Comment: ` [shortGesture requireGestureRecognizerToFail:longGesture];` Add This

Answer (score 0):

You can manage that by using one `UITapGestureRecognizer` like,

```
 self.view.userInteractionEnabled = YES;

UILongPressGestureRecognizer *longGesture = [[UILongPressGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(longGestureOnFormFields:)];
longGesture.minimumPressDuration = 1.0f;
[longGesture setDelegate:self];
[self.view addGestureRecognizer:longGesture];


UITapGestureRecognizer *recog = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc]initWithTarget:self action:@selector(testm)];
[self.view addGestureRecognizer:recog];
```

and your methods smething like,

```
-(void)testm{


NSLog(@"tap");

}

-(void)longGestureOnFormFields : (UILongPressGestureRecognizer*)sender{

   if (sender.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded ) {

       NSLog(@"long press gesture");
   }

}
```

I have added gesture recognizer in `viewDidload` i.e in viewcontroller so i have add it to `self.view` if you have subclass `UIVIew` and adding this to that view then add it on `self` like `[self addgesture...]` as shown in question!